# Is in-browser crypto mining legal?

Tags: united-states, european-union, cryptocurrency

Can I get sued when using an opt-in (prompt the user to accept before starting the miner) crypto miner like coinhive or mineralt on my website in the US/EU?

Comment: Why would the user accept that, unless they simply misunderstand the question and answer "Yes" for the sake of it?

Comment: @Greendrake "Thanks for using our site. We are trying our best to fund our service. Please help us by allowing us to mine cryptocurrency in your browser during your stay on our website"

Comment: @Greendrake It is sometimes used in place of intrusive ads, or can be used as a proof-of-work system to prevent DoS in place of annoying captchas. Especially now that browsers are beginning to support asm.js, mining can be done at nearly native speeds even for brief periods.

Comment: Related: https://law.stackexchange.com/q/27343